# NSAttributedString: How to display a line with different attribute and indent

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit

How to split a string "5 + Bonus Ball" like:

[image]

I'll be assigning this attributed string to label.

Answer (score 0):

`OHAttributedLabel` is in my opinion the best tool to fit this kind of attributed strings in labels.
https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel#sample-code--other-documentation